# Understanding Functional Dependencies and equivalent relations

Tags: sql, functional-dependencies

So I am trying to learn and understand Functional Dependencies and it is very hard to find a clear definition online when it comes to equivalent relations. Can someone please give me a definition and examples on how they work?

For example, if I have the relation

```
R(A,B,C,D)
```

and a set

```
{AB->C, AC->B, AB->CD}.
```

Would something like

```
{AB->C, AC->B, AB->C}
```

be equivalent?

I personally would think so because `AB->CD` to my understanding is the same as `AB-> C and D`.

Comment: `AB->CD` means `AB->C` **and** `AB->D`

Answer (score 2):

In both the sets of functional dependency apply all the inference rules and derive all possible dependencies, now if the enlarged set of FDs are the same (i.e their closures are the same) then these two are equivalent

No both are not equivalent because you can by no means derive that AB->D from the second set